# Close Tag not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tags

I am trying to close a tag in vscode but an error pops up that says command 'auto-close-tag.closeTag' not found. Anyone knows how to fix this?[i am attaching the image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puA3y.png)

Comment: Check the repository of that extension (`auto-close-tag`) and see if there are any similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from line 19. As you can see, you have:

```
<div
```

That is a syntax error in HTML. All div tags must be closed.
You can fix it like this on line 19:

```
<div>
```

Comment: That's the error > tag is not working when i press > key the error pops up command 'auto-close-tag.closeTag' not found